# How to reload Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, variables, google-chrome-extension

I working now on the small Chrome extension and the problem is, if the variable has been created later then the extension started on the page, I cannot read out the value.

This extension place a button to the website, and when I press it, its show me in the console the variable value.
But I need to select an option on the website and just after will create this variable name on the website.

So this is how its work now:

1. Go to https://test.com/ website
2. Extension can see the URL match, so will place the button once the page loaded up
3. I need to select an option from the drop down menu on the website, and this will update the website (but the URL not changing) and create a variable with the value
4. when i press the button the extension cannot read out the value

And becasue just the option has been selected, the website URL not gonna change.

As I see when the extension start, will read out the all variable name, and if this variable not exist for the first start, i cannot read out the value once its has been created on the website.

Comment: Try using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to check for changes in the page.